# Atributos de tipo array en PHP

Tags: php, php7

En PHP, ¿cómo debemos declarar un atributo de una clase que queremos que sea un array?

Forma 1:

```
public $nombreAtributo = array();
```

Forma 2:

```
public $nombreAtributo;
```

Comment: Haciendo un ejercicio de lógica, supongo que PHP sabrá que queremos que `$nombreAtributo` un array cuando le asignemos un array, y no tendrá ni idea de qué es si no le asignamos nada.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Al no ser de tipado estricto PHP no tiene modo de saber que va a almacenar una propiedad/variable hasta el momento que dicho valor le es asignado.

Entonces si yo declaro

```
public $misDatos = array();
```

Es válido, pero si yo declaro

```
public $misDatos;
```

Y posterior yo lo igualó por ejemplo dentro de un método de esta forma también es válido

```
public $misDatos = array('clave1' => 'valor1,....);
```

Ahora por ejemplo la versión más reciente de PHP que es la 7.4 te permite

- Declarar los tipos de datos que una propiedad almacenará
- Además desde que llegó la versión 7 puedes indicar el retorno esperado que un método ha de devolver

Considera este ejemplo

```
 <?php

class Dem
{
    public array $datos;

    public function muestra(): array
    {
     return $datos = array("clave1" => "valor1");
    }
}
$objeto = new Dem;
print_r($objeto->muestra());
```

Que me dará está salida

```
Array
(
    [clave1] => valor1
)
```

**Ejemplo 2**

Para evitar el uso de la declaración del valor que un método ha de retornar con la sintaxis **`:array/string/integer....`**, pudiera quedar de este modo:

**Caso 1**

```
<?php

    class Dem
    {
        public array $datos;

        public function muestra()
        {
         return $this->datos = 12;
        }
    }
    $objeto = new Dem;
    print_r($objeto->muestra());
```

Como estamos igualando a la propiedad con un entero, entonces obtendremos un error de este tipo:

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught TypeError: Typed property Dem::$datos must be array, int used in [...][...]:11

Donde procisamente nos indica que la propiedad tipada debe ser de tipo array y en cambio usamos un entero para darle un valor.

> **En resumidas cuentas la sintaxis que uses para declarar las propiedades y los valores que van a almacenar, dependerá netamente de la versión de PHP que uses.**

Answer (score 2):

```
public $nombreVariable = array();
```

Ni más, ni menos.

Link a la [documentación de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.properties.php)

Comment: Hola, podrías complementar la respuesta del porque la forma que propones es la correcta (algo de documentación tal vez), ésto sobre todo para que la información sea más valiosa para los que lean ésta respuesta. Saludos ;)

Comment: recordad que eso seria para versiones anteriores de php. A partir de php 7.0 (creo recordar) ya podemos utilizar la forma de $variable= []; Tambien podeis pensar en usar objetos de tipo ArrayCollection (hay frameworks que ya incluyen esos objetos) que tienen metodos de add, search, remove ...

Comment: Disculpa Israel, ha sido la costumbre, pero efectivamente, en la documentación está. He editado para añadir el link. Gracias